# How do i convert HH:MM:SS into just seconds using C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Is there a tidy way of doing this rather than doing a split on the colon's and multipling out each section the relevant number to calculate the seconds?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It looks like a timespan. So simple parse the text and get the seconds.

```
string time = "00:01:05";
double seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use the parse method on aTimeSpan.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse( "10:20:30" );
double totalSeconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

The TotalSeconds property returns the total seconds if you just want the seconds then use the seconds property

```
int seconds = ts.Seconds;
```

Seconds return '30'.
TotalSeconds return 10 * 3600 + 20 * 60 + 30

Answer (score 12):

TimeSpan.Parse() will parse a formatted string.

So

```
TimeSpan.Parse("03:33:12").TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 2):

This code allows the hours and minutes components to be optional.  For example,

"30" -> 24 seconds
"1:30" -> 90 seconds
"1:1:30" -> 3690 seconds

```
int[] ssmmhh = {0,0,0};
var hhmmss = time.Split(':');
var reversed = hhmmss.Reverse();
int i = 0;
reversed.ToList().ForEach(x=> ssmmhh[i++] = int.Parse(x));                           
var seconds = (int)(new TimeSpan(ssmmhh[2], ssmmhh[1], ssmmhh[0])).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Added code to handle invalid strings
string time = null; //"";//"1:31:00";
string rv = "0";
TimeSpan result;
if(TimeSpan.TryParse(time, out result))
{
    rv = result.TotalSeconds.ToString();
}
retrun rv;
```